# How do I delay animate, not whileOver or WhileTap in framer motion?

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

Im want to delay animation of each button im mapping out when the component mounts, but not when hovering or clicking the buttons. Now I get the delay allways.

Any ideas?

```
<motion.button
                className={distanse === place ? "aktiv" : null}
                initial={{
                  opacity: 0,
                  y: -200,
                  rotate: 180,
                }}
                animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0, rotate: 0 }}
                transition={{
                  type: "spring",
                  stiffness: 150,
                  delay: Math.random(),
                  duration: 2,
                }}
                whileHover={{ scale: 1.3 }}
                whileTap={{ scale: 0.9, rotate: 45 }}
                key={i}
                type="button"
                value={place}
                onClick={handleDistanceChange}
              >
                {place === "10km" ? "Mål" : place}
              </motion.button>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can add a transition key to the animate object itself:

```
animate={{
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0, 
    rotate: 0,
    transition: {
        type: "spring",
        stiffness: 150,
        delay: Math.random(),
        duration: 2,
    }
}}
```

Alternatively if this doesn't work, I can see in the documentation here: https://www.framer.com/docs/gestures/

```
<motion.button
  whileHover={{
    scale: 1.2,
    transition: { duration: 1 },
  }}
  whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
/>
```

that you can use this pattern with the gesture objects, so you could perhaps nullify the transition in there.

Comment: Great, transition in animate worked. Thanx!